# Autotools - selecting library versions to link with

Tags: c, autotools

I have a project that links to libssl.so and I'm hitting a bug in libssl and never versions of the lib fixes it. However on the system I'm working I don't have root account so I've built libssl and prerequirements myself under `$HOME/opt`.

Now, when I'm doing:

```
./configure --prefix=`$HOME/opt`
make
```

the build system still uses the older system-wide version of libssl.

I'm trying to find the proper way to "hack" autotools to link with libs I've compiled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's always `./configure LDFLAGS=-L$HOME/opt/lib CPPFLAGS=-I$HOME/opt/include`.  But that method globally uses headers from that prefix and globally links against libs located there.
Many projects provide `AC_ARG_WITH`s to allow to customise paths, e.g.

```
AC_ARG_WITH([ssl], ...)
```

or

```
AC_ARG_WITH([ssl-prefix], ...)
AC_ARG_WITH([ssl-libs], ...)
AC_ARG_WITH([ssl-includes], ...)
```

in analogy to autoconf's `--x-includes` and `--x-libraries`

But I guess it's a question of personal taste.

Just noticed you don't want to change your files, in that case you could just add the library in question to the the `LIBS` variable, or use an rpath:

```
./configure LIBS="$HOME/opt/lib/libssl.so.x.y.z"
```

or

```
./configure LDFLAGS="-Wl,-rpath,$HOME/opt/lib/"
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure, but perhaps you should also add the new path to the `PKG_CONFIG_PATH`. That is, if your project uses `PKG_CHECK_MODULES` for finding libssl.

Comment: I do not want to modify any of my source files just to workaround my specific problem.

Comment: You don't need to change your source files in order to set environment variables: you can run ./configure PKG_CONFIG_PATH=$HOME/opt/lib/pkgconfig .

Answer (score 0):

It seems that:

```
LDFLAGS="-L$HOME/opt/lib" ../configure --prefix="$HOME/opt"
```

is forcing autotools to try `$HOME/opt/lib` **first**. If anybody knows better or more general answer I'm still all ears.